# Class loading problem in using javaagent with Grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy, embedded-jetty

I wrote a javaagent that can debug web applications remotely. It works fine in many frameworks, like Tomcat, Jetty, and even Scala Play. Since Groovy is also running on JVM, I wondered could it be used for Grails.

Before describing what I've tried. I should explain my agent a little. It starts an embedded-jetty server and provides debugging interfaces. I also wrote a custom class loader to load all classes my agent uses.

So, first I ensured the agent works fine on groovy local application. Then I added javaagent parameters to JAVA_OPTS, and started Grails application. In premain phase, the jetty server started successfully, but when I sent requests to the debugging interface, it returned nothing and a warning message about class loading could be found in the console.

I designed my javaagent following the JVM specification strictly(I think), and since it can be used in other frameworks, I wonder is there anything special in Grails' class loading?

My agent: https://github.com/uniquetruth/remote-debug-agent/tree/grail_research
You can figure out how to use it in README simply. You can use the release directly too, but need to change jetty's log level in the jar file. In the branch code, I've already turned Jetty's log on, and added join() for Jetty server, so that I can block premain phase and debug faster.
Java version: 1.8
Groovy version: 4.0.2
Grails version: 5.1.8
web application: the default helloworld demo of Grails is ok.
after application starts, send this request to debug interface `http://localhost:8098/trace/`
expectation: return some text
current situation: nothing returns and warning found in console:

> org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$Accept failed
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput

There is even no stack trace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out by myself. It's not about class loading, Grails starts applications in forked mode, if I set JAVA_OPTS in shell, the grails CLI takes it, not the real application.

The correct way to add JAVA_OPTS to grails application in forked mode is to edit the bootRun configuration in the build.gradle file.

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs('JAVA_OPTS')
}
```